# Modelize some filter component with React

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to reactJS and I was wondering how to render this :

I have a form with 3 filter (dropdown) but those dropdowns are populated through database. This is what I tried :

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from "axios";

export default class Filter extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {rarity: [], typpeequipement: []};
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.all([
            axios.get('api/rari'),
            axios.get('api/type'),
        ])
            .then(axios.spread((rar, type) => {
                this.setState({rarity: rar.data, type: type.data})
            }));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="carac" id="carac-principale">
                /* some dropdown */
                {this.state.rarity}
                /* some dropdown */
                {this.state.type}
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

And my form with those all 3 filters :

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Filter from 'filter';
export default class SearchForm extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="filter">
                <div className="tosearch">
                    {Filter.render()}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

I don't know what the good approach would be to populate my dropdowns with the data. Is it a good idea to split the filters I want to render from the form I want to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call  `render` explicitly; React do it for you once the component is mounted. To show the data inside the dropdowns, just loop over the data fetched and set the values/options.

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="carac" id="carac-principale">
      <select>
        {
          this.state.rarity.Map((rarity) => (
            <option value={rarity.id}>{ rarity.name }</option>
          ))
        }
      </select>
      <select>
        {
          this.state.type.map((type) => (
            <option value={type.id}>{ type.name }</option>
          ))
        }
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Aditionally, if you want to set the choosed value of the dropdowns inside a model/object, need to set the `value` and `onChange` props to them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can't I do the render all of my filters in another file and put them in the final form? Not sure I understood well

Comment: The main feature of React is what you said. You can use all components that you need and insert them inside some other component.